# throw exception helps me display my javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am getting an error pop up which allows my javascript to show a new window. But with out it the new window will not pop up.

This is the code I comment out and the error goes away. But my code to pop up a new javascript wont show either.

```
//rgLogistics.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(rgLogistics_ItemCommand);
```

Seems like this error helps me pop up the new window.

```
    private void rgLogistics_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
```

if I comment this out my javascript new window will not pop up either. Any help apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact popup you are referring to? How to you open it? What event do you use? Do you use AJAX? What is your grid code and how does the ItemCommand relate to the popup and to the scripts you need to call?

My best guess at this point is that you have captured an error event or the exception and this is where your logic for opening the popup executes, so you need to move it to the appropriate place (e.g., register the script from the ItemCommand handler instead of throwing exceptions).